# decompose() in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very confused as to what `.decompose()` does in `BeautifulSoup` - I've read the docs. But this is just one of those docs that isn't clicking.

I'm working on a personal project to scrape some data from website. For work we use BS4 for testing purposes. As it's been explained to me, every time we parse a page, we instantiate a `HTMLParser()`, which is `BeautifulSoup(html, features="html5lib")`. Once we're done, we need to `destroy()` it. This `destroy` method is simply calling `.decompose()` on the `BeautifulSoup` object itself.

I'm just curious as to what `decompose` is doing and why we need to do it.

Comment: where did you read _This destroy method is simply calling .decompose() on the BeautifulSoup object itself_  out of interest?

Comment: the `destroy()` was a custom method - sorry should have specified

Comment: As mentioned in the docs `Tag.decompose() removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents` The `.decompose()` function destroys the given tag ( in your case unwanted ones) and thus makes just the content needed available

Comment: Yeah i read the docs. My question was, _why do we need to do this_? Memory issues?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.decompose()` just to edit or modify your html document.
When you want to remove a tag because it is not needed anymore.